k8s indexed jobs - How to group pods together onto a single node?
I am running an EKS 1.29 cluster with managed nodegroups along with cluster-autoscaler.
The nodegroup that I use to run my k8s indexed jobs scales down to zero, when there are no jobs. One node can accomodate upto 4 jobs, enforced using resources.requests of Pod spec.
I have to run a job (kind: Job) with parallelism: 100, completions: 100 and completionMode: Indexed with an added complexity. I want Pods to be scheduled according to job-completion-index values. In this case, Pods with job-completion-index: 0-3 should be scheduled on same node, Pods with job-completion-index: 4-7 should be scheduled on same node and so on. I am looking for a soft preference for the scheduler, it need not be enforced.
How can I do this?

I can think of two methods that maybe used to meet your requirement.

Develop a scheduler plugin for this kind of job, and inject the node affinity based on the index of pod and node, to match with each other, for example, exec-job-0 will have int(0/4), so it'll be placed to exec-node-<0%4>, so it'll exec-node-0, exec-job-5 will have int(5/4), and it'll be placed to exec-node-1. If the node name is not predictable, maybe you should implement the mapping in the scheduler.

Use podAffinity and podAntiAffinity, for exec-job-0/4/8, let's call it lead pod on each node, inject a special label to these pods and let them schedule to different nodes using podAntiAffinity. The for the follwing pod, use podAffinity to schedule to the same node as its lead pod.
For example, lead pod exec-job-0 on node-0 have label: job-head-pod(for podAntiAffinity) and job-group-0(for podAffinity), then for all head pod will be scheduled to different node due to job-head-pod label, and exec-job-1 will use podAffinity job-group-0 and scheduled to node-0.



Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
